# NPM build is hanging in azure dev ops

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops, npm-build

This may be a similar issue to this question: [npm run build hangs indefinitely on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682754/npm-run-build-hangs-indefinitely-on-azure-ci-cd-pipelines).

Our build has worked fine for months.  Now for some reason npm build will not work in azure.  The code can build locally, but no code version will work in azure.  Here is where it hangs:
[image]

Here is what the pipeline looks like:
[image]

Comment: any suggestions on where to start?  The last few times something like this happened, it turned out it was npm itself down (Oct. 17th) https://status.npmjs.org/.   Any logs in azure you recommend?  There are no errors when the code is built on my local.  So I am not receiving any indications of an issue there.

Comment: Any other information I could share to improve the question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Changing the Node version to 16.x fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I appreciate the answers to my question.  I agree it was very vague in nature and appreciate the resources given.  For those who navigate here with a similar vague problem, here is the solution we found.

We set up a virtual box and built our code to test what was happening.  It turned out that it was version 17 of node.js that was causing our problem.  Version 16.x worked perfectly.

Though not satisfactory, this was the cause of our build hanging.  Of course, we have a lot of further investigation to do to understand why this version is giving us trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [bsoulier](https://github.com/bsoulier) ,Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

"You can replace my "npm" task with a "Command line" task that runs npm and sets the environment variable `max_old_space_size`

[image]

"

Please check the below links for more information:

GitHub: [NPM task sometimes hangs](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4427)

Developer community : [NPM install hangs from 60 minutes](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/npm-install-hangs-60-minutes/575241)

If you are still facing the issue please raise a ticket in [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) or in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues) .

Comment: Thanks for this answer, we did finally figure out what the issue was.

Comment: Can I ask what was the solution?